# Programmatically logon to a external website from my asp.net website

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms-authentication

I have an aspx application. A button click from the application should invoke login to another external website with the username and password. The username and password is available in my application. How can i achieve this? Can i capture the login event of the external link?

Comment: Kindly provide more detail about the application which you want to access. Also it is less likely that you can directly login to another web site.

Comment: go for web service or wcf services

Comment: You will not be able to do it client side (due to same origin policy), server side should be trivial to implement, also it may not really help you.